# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'die'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an absolute beginner in Python and I am learning the Python code for a week or so. I am reading the Python crash course 2nd. And I come across a rolling die Python script in chapter 15. The script is as below, after I run it and it keeps saying that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'die'`.  I indeed tried the exact codes as published in the book but the error still exists.

```
import plotly as py
from random import randint

class Die:
    """A class representing a single die."""

def __init__(self, num_sides=6):
    """Assume a six-side die."""
    self.num.sides = num_sides

def roll(self):
    """Return a random value between 1 and number of sides."""
    return randint(1, self.num_sides)

from die import Die

# Create a D6
die = Die()

# Make some rolls, and store results in a list
results =[]

for roll_num in range(100):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

print(results)
```

Comment: That was presumably intended to be two separate files, with the part before `from die import Die` being named `die.py` so that the second file can import it.

Comment: Got it. thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be in two parts, the first part:

```
from die import Die

# Create a D6
die = Die()

# Make some rolls, and store results in a list
results =[]

for roll_num in range(100):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

print(results)
```

Put it in a file, maybe `main.py`

And put this one:

```
import plotly as py
from random import randint

class Die:
    """A class representing a single die."""

def __init__(self, num_sides=6):
    """Assume a six-side die."""
    self.num.sides = num_sides

def roll(self):
    """Return a random value between 1 and number of sides."""
    return randint(1, self.num_sides)
```

inside a file named `die.py` in the same directory as `main.py`, your directory structure must look like this now:

```
.
├── die.py
└── main.py
```

Then run `main.py`

Answer (score 1):

The line

> from die import Die

means that you want to import object `Die` from module `die`.

Module `die` may be a file `die.py`.

In this case you want to define your class `Die` in a file called `die.py` and import it (`from die import Die`) from another file.

If there's no file `die.py` in the same directory and there is no module called `die` you will get an error ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to use your own Die class, right? If so, you must not import Die afterwards. There the error occurs. python does not find a package called die, so you get an import (ModueNotFound) error. Just remove the `from die import Die` line and you should be fine:

```
import plotly as py
from random import randint

class Die:
    """A class representing a single die."""

def __init__(self, num_sides=6):
    """Assume a six-side die."""
    self.num.sides = num_sides

def roll(self):
    """Return a random value between 1 and number of sides."""
    return randint(1, self.num_sides)

#from die import Die remove this line

# Create a D6
die = Die()

# Make some rolls, and store results in a list
results =[]

for roll_num in range(100):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

print(results)
```

Comment: If you prefer to split the script into two files, chek out @RMPR s answer!

Answer (score 0):

your first porblem is import die
second indenting for Die methods
third in the init method self.num.side is wrong ==> self.num_side
Try this code. I hope this will help you :))

```
import plotly as py
from random import randint

class Die:
    """A class representing a single die."""

    def __init__(self, num_sides=6):
        """Assume a six-side die."""
        self.num_sides = num_sides

    def roll(self):
        """Return a random value between 1 and number of sides."""
        return randint(1, self.num_sides)


# Create a D6
die = Die()

# Make some rolls, and store results in a list
results =[]

for roll_num in range(100):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

print(results)
```

Comment: Got it. Thx a lot!